# eclipse dynamic web project with groovy nature copies .groovy files

Tags: eclipse, deployment, groovy, web, project

I have an eclipse dynamic web project, and it has some groovy files (not a grails project though, just using groovy for some small backend stuff). I have added src/main/groovy as a source folder. However, when I select "Run on Server", it copies the actual .groovy file as if it were a resource. Is there a way to fix this behavior?

Comment: Is this a maven project?  I'm guessing so.  How are you compiling your groovy files?  gmaven or groovy-eclipse-compiler?

Comment: It is a gradle project, but I'm not sure it's related to that. When I actually compile the files (using the groovy-eclipse-compiler), the groovy files are compiled to class files. But when I do a "Run on Server", it looks like Eclipse is copying the groovy files over as well, so I end up with MyObj.groovy and MyObj.class on the web server.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the exact same issue here. I have a web project here using the following:

Eclipse Kepler
Gradle
Groovy 
Spring MVC

I have a Tomcat set inside Eclipse, from the command line or from the Gradle view I can compile, assemble and generate war files, however when I try to "Run on server" the files being deployed to Tomcat are the .groovy files, not the actual .class files, even though they are successfully generated inside the build/classes/main folder

So, TO FIX this I deleted and then re-created the Tomcat server within eclipse, after doing that it was able to find and deploy the right set of files compiled by Gradle

Hope this helps